# event observer inventory change configuration

Tags: event-observer, configuration

I tried to observe a quantity change event but I messed up with the config file a bit

config.xml:

```
    <events>
        <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after >
            <observers>
                <unreal_bisn>
                    <class>unreal_bisn/observer</class>
                    <method>productBackInStock</method>
                </unreal_bisn>
            </observers>
        </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after >
    </events>
```

Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Unreal_Bisn_Model_Observer
{

    public function productBackInStock()
    {
        die("Worked");
    }

}
```

When I change the qty of a product I see a warning that shows me I did a wrong configuration of namespaces somehow

```
Warning: include(Mage\Unreal\Bisn\Model\Observer.php):
```

It should be

```
Unreal\Bisn\Model\Observer.php
```

Please let me know what to adjust.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the model?

```
<global>
     <models>
          <unreal_bisn><class>Unreal_Bisn_Model</class></unreal_bisn>
     </models>
</global>
```

Also, I can't remember if you'll break/confuse things using `<unreal_bisn>` inside `<observer>`, I'd use `<unreal_bisn_observer>` for that.

Comment: weee thanks! I did not have had the model, I'll accept the answer as soon as I can